# how to custom restart strategy after 5 second in Erlang/Elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir

In Erlang/Elixir, it could restart child when the child crashed.
I have a gen_server which hold database connection.
I want crash the process if the connection can't achieved and restart it after 5 seconds（or more complex regular, such as first restart is 100ms, second time is 500ms, third is 1s ...）.

How to config the supervisor to handle the restart time?
As default, The gen_server will be attempt to restart endlessly.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/pouriya-jahanbakhsh/director

Comment: @Pouriya, it seems the library add more lifetime compare to standard supervisor. Will it not break other features like hot code reload?

Comment: Hot code reloading with any erlang module can be simply done, when you don't want to change the state. actually it does, and I tried to have some scenarios in its test code for that and those test are passed, https://github.com/Pouriya-Jahanbakhsh/director/blob/master/test/director_SUITE.erl#L507

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle that logic (called 'exponential backoff') in your own code because `Supervisor` is simply just handling monitoring and restarts of children.

There are some packages that help facilitate this you can find on https://hex.pm (search for `exponential backoff`)

But also check your database client/library, most of them handle this out of the box - at least anything that uses the `db_connection` library like most ecto clients, mongodb, etc.

So, you should be able to simply adjust your config for your database client and things should just work.

Comment: Hi, I'm use Ecto, but haven't see how to setting  exponential backoff. The `retry` library give a high download on hex, not exactly know it will work with Ecto because the library not used on supervisor.

Comment: there are document on [Ecto db_connection](https://hexdocs.pm/db_connection/DBConnection.ConnectionPool.html#content) project. but not document shows how to use the backoff opts.